# Why do we use degrees?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, angle

I see a lot of people who ask why we use radians instead of degrees.
But why do we use degrees instead of radians.
In the cases we use degrees instead of radians, what convenience does it bring?
The only benefit I see is eyeballing small angles, but that's probably because I don't measure angles everyday.
So, what are the practical benefits?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)#History

Comment: +1 I've read it a million times before. Ain't mathematical history fascinating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historical precedent and continuity. You can read about the history in the link in the comments, but it's really just tradition.

Comment: Note that the *grade* (1 turn = 400 grades, so that a right angle measures 100 grades) was introduced during the French Revolution. But it didn't stick,contrary to the metric system. So traditions may be hard to change.

Comment: I guess somethings just don't change, do they?

Also, the thing about being divisible by multiple numbers is also there with radians. Just multiply the denominator by the factor. I should've asked what practical uses degrees have today, which is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

$360$ has lots of nice divisors.

Comment: This is actually a very good argument when you consider how many nice whole number divisors $2\pi$ has.

Comment: You beat me to it :P

Comment: Evidently, $2\pi$ has a factor $2$ which is a whole number (joke; use $\tau$, however).

Answer (score 2):

Having 360 degrees be a full circle may seem a bit odd of a number to use, but it's actually very practical. If we find the prime factors of it, then we can understand why it is useful and practical.
$360 \rightarrow 180 \rightarrow 90 \rightarrow 45 \rightarrow 15 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 1$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \div2 \ \ \ \ \div2 \ \ \ \ \div2 \ \ \ \div3 \ \ \ \div3 \ \ \div5$

$ 2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5^1 = 360$

We can divide this number by $2$ 3 times, divide by $3$ 2 times and divide by $5$ 1 time and still have it be whole! Halves, thirds and fifths are the fractions we most commonly come across and use due to them being the lowest prime numbers, and we generally use lower prime numbers more than higher ones (that's why you can divide 3 times by $2$ and only once by $5$). This is what makes the number convenient and practical.

Answer (score 2):

Number of days in a year is likely the reason. If the year had 400+/- days, we'd probably have a 400 degree standard.

Comment: +1 While historians are still debating the validity of this argument, it is indeed compelling. After 360 days, the night sky looks exactly the same at midnight from some given spot on Earth. I usually give this as an argument to my students for the 360 story. Ha,everyone believes it! By the time they found out, that 365 is a much better fit, no one wanted to rewrite the Geometry that was discovered up till thus far.

Comment: By the time degrees were introduced the Babylonians as well as the Greeks knew very well that a year has about 365.25 days. We know even better how long a year is and still use a banker's year, at least in school.